# Mongoose doesn't insert in MongoLab

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mlab, nosql

I'm trying to build my first MEAN Stack application and I'm using postman to check my insertion in my DB and I get a message that says "user created!", but after checking the DB in MongoLab. I do not get any document inserted in the collections. here's my code:

Here's my repo in case you need it: https://github.com/pevargasg/joberistyNode

app.js

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var morgan = require('morgan');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//My one modules
var User = require('./app/models/user');
var Company = require('./app/models/company');

//Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(morgan('dev'));

//Connection to DB
//mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
//Feel free to use your own mongoLab link below for testing purposes
mongoose.connect('mongodb://user:password@dsXXXXXX.mlab.com:19768/jobersity',function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log("Not connection to DB" + err);
        throw err;
    }
    else{
        console.log("Connected to DB");
    }
});
//Routes
/*app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})*/

//Creating Users
app.post('/users',function(req,res){
    //res.send('test');
    var user = new User();       
    user.username = req.body.username;
    user.password = req.body.password;
    user.email = req.body.email;
    /*user.firstName = req.body.firstName;
    user.lastName = req.body.lastName;    
    user.major = req.body.major;*/

    //Save user
    user.save(); 
    res.send('user created!');


});
```

user.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//Table for usersSchema
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    username:{type: String, lowercase: true, required: true, unique: true},
    password:{type: String, required: true},
    email:{type: String, lowercase: true, required: true, unique: true},
    /*firstName: {type: String, required: true},
    lastName: {type: String, required: true},   
    major: {type: String, required: true},
    jobsApplied:[{
        title: String,
        description: String,
        position: String
    }]*/
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Comment: Code is actually working I was testing the wrong way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works successfully when I run it.

Two things I did notice:

1. Your `package.json` file includes `mongojs` when it doesn't seem to get used. The `mongooose` package will pull the mongodb dependency it need when you call `npm install`.
2. Your connection string is included in clear text in your repository. Try to get in the habit of importing any sensitive information into your app through a config file.

For example, create a config file, e.g. `./config/db.js`:

```
module.exports = {
   'uri' : 'mongodb://user:pwd@host1:port1/dbname'
}
```

Then import the file into your app:

```
var dbConfig = require('./config/db.js');
```

The variable can then be used be used in your code:

```
mongoose.connect( dbConfig.uri, function(err){ ... } )
```

Finally, add this file (`./config/db.js`) to your `.gitignore`.